# How do I define hexadecimal RBG triplets for ZSH?

Tags: colors, zsh, zshrc

According to the ZSH manual, for ZSH V5.1+ colors should be able to be defined as a # followed by an RGB color code as a hexadecimal triplet, for eg. `#ff00ff`. However, I have found no documentation that provides a concrete example to demonstrate how exactly this is achieved, and no matter how I try to define a color variable, it never seems to produce the color I want (or any color for that matter). I have tried all of the following formats and none have worked so far when I attempt to use them in `%F` or `%K` in the prompt definition (eg. `PS1="%F{$var} >> %f"`)

```
var=#ff00ff
var="#ff00ff"
var='#ff00ff'
var=$"#ff00ff"
var=$'#ff00ff'
```

I am running the shell in the kitty terminal emulator, which has truecolor support enabled by default.
All 255 color numbers (eg. `var=231`) in zsh work just fine, color names (eg. `yellow`) as well.
I am currently running ZSH V5.5.1.
I have looked for information on the zsh manual page [] and so far nohing more than a mention about it is provided.

I'm looking for an example of how to define hex code colors (and assign them to variables) in no uncertain terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experimentation, I determined that the problem was partly the documentation, and partly the version. In essence, to declare hex triples in zsh you use the format `var='#f0f0f0'`. For this to work it is required that you have ZSH V5.7+, despite what the documentation may say about it working in ZSH V5.1+

I hope this answer will be helpful to anybody else who encounters this difficulty.